# How do I install Ubuntu on an external hard drive alongside my Windows 8.1?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8

How do I install Ubuntu on windows 8.1 alongside my external hard drive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

You would just like installing on an internal drive, but once you get to the screen where you choose a drive, make sure that you choose your external drive.  Also make sure that you partition the empty space on it, just to be on the safe side, if you have any important data on the drive, make sure that its backed up.  For more info see [Installing Ubunut](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest).

You may have to Turn off fast boot and disable secure boot.

[Extra info](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

When u install ubuntu it gives u a list of all the places u can install it on.  The primary hard drive is called sda, and the patitions are called sda1 sda2 etc.  Any other external harddrives or flashdrives are called sdb, sdc and so on.  If u have any questions plz email me as iv done this many times before.  Here is my email: darthmaulyou@gmail.com
Thx